# Add CSS dynamically to non-sibling div using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code, I want to add the `display` property to div when `test()` function fired. I call the function many times in the same file and want it to work for each button individually.

At the moment, if I click on any button it adds the CSS to first `inline-data` div, not the one I clicked for. What do I need to change so that it works for the `inline-data` that matches with the button?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"> 

  <style>
    .inline-data {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button onclick="test()">Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button onclick="test()">Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button onclick="test()">Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function test() {
      document.querySelector(".inline-data").style.display = "flex";
    }
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in jquery you can dynamically add css like this `$(".inline-data").css('display', 'flex');`.

Comment: So you want each button add flex to its individual `inline-data` element?

Comment: If you need to undo this it would be easier to toggle a class instead and use css rule(s) in that class

Comment: @AndrewL64 Yes, you are right. But how can I do it without adding any extra classes?

Comment: Can you use jquery ?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I know It is just an example,I want to toggle it but individually

Comment: @Swati Yes of course, I tried but its not working individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in the `test()` function, you would need to pass in which button is clicked, and do something similar to below.

Instead you can di ut all in one single function - remove the `onClick` from each button and this function will trigger on all button clicks:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find("div.inline-data").css("display", "flex");
});
```

This finds the `tr` ancestor of the button that was clicked and then looks for child/grandchild elements with the `inline-data`. When it finds them, it adds your CSS.

*Note - if you don't want this to work for some buttons, you van give those buttons a class and then select that class in the selector e.g. `$( "button.myclass" ).click(...`*

**Working Snippet**

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").find("div.inline-data").css("display", "flex");
});
```

```css
.inline-data {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Working Snippet with test() function**

If you need it to work with the existing HTML and the `test` function, you can doe it this way:

```js
function test(clicked_button) {
      $(clicked_button).closest("tr").find("div.inline-data").css("display", "flex");
    }
```

```css
.inline-data {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button onclick="test(this)">Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button onclick="test(this)">Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>data 2</span>
        <div class="inline-data">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><button onclick="test(this)">Click</button></td>      
    </tr>
  </table>
```